# Remote Event Receiver in Hostweb

Tags: 2013, remote-event-receiver

I have a Farm Solution that management is pushing to be ported to the App Model. This Farm solution has a Custom Action which, when configured, dynamically attaches a ListItem Event Receiver to the List chosen by the user.

Is it possible to attach a Remote Event Receiver to a list programmatically ? Can you add a Remote Event Receiver to the Host Web or does it have to exist in the App Web attached to a list in the App Web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question "**Is it possible to attach a Remote Event Receiver to a list programmatically?**, The answer is ***YES***. Yes it is possible to attach the remote event receiver programmatically.

We can make use of `EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation` class to make this possible in `AppInstalled` event.

For your query there is perfect article written here

- [Attaching Remote Event Receivers to Lists in the Host Web](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/)
- [RER to Lists in the Host Web](https://mythoughttech.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/)
- [Adding Remote Event Receivers to list on Host web + Debugging](http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2015/01/adding-remote-event-receivers-to-list.html)

Let me know if you have any additional issue in implementing this.

Comment: when AppInstalled runs, I still won't know the List the user wants to attach the event receiver to. I will only know when they click a Custom Action link in the Ribbon or Settings (The user needs to choose the List) . Can you see a flow like this working? List Settings => Custom Action => AppWeb UI => RER => Attach RER to List ?

Comment: Or maybe they can pick a List from a Drop down in the AppWeb UI, if I could query the Host web for all Lists

Comment: We can always query the Host Web list in App Web.